# count a specific word in string in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am new at programming. please help me to solve this program :

> the program gets a string and a word , and check the number of occurrences of that word in the string using c\c++.

thank you vary much

this is my first post.

Comment: Please give an example, what do you want actually ?

Comment: You need to give an example.  Do you want to count 'word' or 'substring'?  What are legal inputs, like space, punctuation symbols, tab, carriage-return, English characters, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find number of occurrence of a `pattern or word` in a string you can use [KMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) algorithm.

It will give you the total number of occurrences of a word in a string.

Example :

```
string  = "abaabcabaabd"  
word    = "aba"
```

Output will be 2,  **aba**abc**aba**abd

Complexity : `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the string

**UPDATE 1:**
I don't know actually what problem you are talking about :(
But if you want to count number of words like this example :

```
string : hi how are you how are hi how
word   : how
```

`how` contain 3 times. `hi *how* are you *how* are hi *how*`

If your problem is like this, then this program will do :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str,word;
    getline(cin,str);
    getline(cin,word);

    stringstream ss(str);
    int cnt=0;
    while(ss>>str)
    {
        if(str==word)
          cnt++;
    }
    cout<<cnt<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Using pointer to solve same problem :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[100],word[100];
    gets(str);
    gets(word);

    char *token=strtok(str," ");

    int cnt=0;
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(token,word)==0)
          cnt++;
        token=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    cout<<cnt<<"\n";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: how can i write this program with pointers?

Comment: do you want output like i described ?

Comment: yes exactly, but with pointers please

Comment: do you need whole program to be pointer based ? or just compare portion ?

Comment: Edited...
i think you wanted something like this :)
if it does then please accept the answer